How to resolve the database connectivity error in Red Hat Open Shift devspaces
I am trying to set up my existing project in Red Hat Open Shift Devspaces.
I used the devfile.yaml to set up the workspaces in red hat open shift devspaces. It uses the URL of the imagestream of red hat open shift  in the container section :
My devfile looks like this :
schemaVersion: 2.3.0
metadata:
  name: new-java-angular
  displayName: new-java-angular
  tags:
    - Java
    - Node.js
    - Angular
  projectType: Angular
  language: TypeScript,Java
  provider: Red Hat
  version: 2.2.1
components:
  - container:
      endpoints:
        - name: java
          protocol: https
          targetPort: 8080
      image: image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:2000/internal-images/devspacesimg5
      args: ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
      memoryLimit: 1024Mi 
      env :
        - name : AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          value: "xay"
        - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          value: "xya"
    name: java
commands:
  - id: install
    exec:
      commandLine: npm install
      component:   angular
      group:
        isDefault: true
        kind: build
      workingDir: /projects/test-angular 
 

My project uses the postgres sql which is running in the docker conatiner :
docker run --name hpsapf-postgres --restart unless-stopped -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=password -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pwd -d -p 5432:5432 postgres:14
How can I achieve this step for the Red Hat Open Shift Devspaces.
My db details are mentioned in pom.xml :
<configuration>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>--filter-file=${project.build.directory}/classes/filtering/hpsapf-filterfile.properties</argument>
                        <argument>--property-encryption-password=password</argument>    
                        <argument>--batch.database.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/fp?currentSchema=fp</argument>
                        <argument>--batch.database.user=fp</argument>
                        <argument>--batch.database.password=fp</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <jvmArguments>-Xdebug
                        -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8787</jvmArguments>
                </configuration>

How can I replicate this database set up in Red Hat Open shift Devspaces?
I have tried create the postgres db host in deploymentconfig of the red hat open shift and refer the service host name in pom.xml and deploy it again but still it was not resolving and could not connect to database
